# how to change the text of TextField in java fx 2

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, textfield, javafx-2

I have a `TextField` in which there is some text but I want to change that text on some event but I am getting the `NullPointerException`.

I am using `setText()` method but still its not working. I am calling that function from other class .

Any Help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you get NPE when calling setText on a textfield, then that textfield probably does not exist or you misspelled it, hence the NPE. Please post relevant code and im sure we can help you with this task

Comment: solved it but thanks fr reply bro :)

Answer (score 6):

At beginning of the controller's class definition:

```
@FXML private TextField txtDescription;
```

Within the initialize method, add:

```
txtDescription = new TextField();
```

Within a method that acts on that text field, something like:

```
txtDescription.setText("This is my new text.");
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) @sergey actually it was mistake in my part. The setText() method works fine its just rather than making it local i make that global and static.

Comment: you don't need to initialize it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a TextField definition in your **.fxml** file with the following:

```
 fx:id="myCoolTextField"
```

If you don't have that, init the text field in your display() method with the following:

```
myCoolTextField = new TextField();
```

You may also override the special *initialize()* method. This method is being called every time your scene updated.

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    myCoolTextField.setText("Here is my updated text.");
}
```